# get tangent line on particular point of curve?

Tags: c#, silverlight, image-processing, graphics

My Idea or Project:

I want to develop an application which takes an image as input and returns another image as output.
For example: I have a bitmap image with a circle drawn inside it. What i want to develop is an algorithm that will draw another circle inside it. I know this is rather easy but it should work for any kind of starting image like a triangle or any other shape.

According to me, I have to go through the shape's inside-periphery and draw a line. 
However, I am having problems with dynamic shapes. The problem is easy for circles, elipses and rectangles as we know the algorithm but becomes hard for any other shape.

Any thoughts as to how I can achieve this? If I can get tangent line on a particular  point of  the curve then I could also do what I need.

Comment: OpenCV sounds like a perfect match for this project. Its written in C/C++ but easily wrappable with C++/CLI and then you can use it in your C# project. Or use EMGU OpenCV wrappers for .Net. they have example projects detecting locations of objects (circle, box, triangle).. there is also OpenCV.Net...but if your familiar with C++ your better off doing the entire thing in C++...

Comment: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Shape_(Triangle,_Rectangle,_Circle,_Line)_Detection_in_CSharp

Comment: Thank you .....I will surly check it out. .

Comment: I have looked that project that is EMGU CV library.I am very happy to learn from that.It is very nice library.Thank you for that. But i didn't found any help from that. Can you tell me how can tell me how it is helpfull to me. Just tell me class name or flow i will work on that.

Comment: Thank you very much i found something from that. . . . now need to work on that,  http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Shape_%28Triangle,_Rectangle,_Circle,_Line%29_Detection_in_CSharp#Source_Code

Comment: EMGU made it very simple... Support is great too.

Comment: EMGU is not working for me ......